# Virtually $\mathbb{Z}$ implies $\mathbb{Z}$ is central

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups

Let $G$ be a (EDIT: torsion-free) virtually $\mathbb{Z}$-group, i.e., there is a subgroup $H \leq G$ of finite index isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}$. WLOG, we can suppose $H$ is normal in $G$ - otherwise exchange $H$ with the kernel of the action of $G$ on the permutation set $S(G/H)$ - which must also be isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}$ as it is contained in $H$.

> Is $H$ is central in $G$?

I guess so. Because $|\text{Aut}(H)| = 2$ and the kernel of the conjugation map $G \to \text{Aut}(H)$ is the centralizer $Z_G(H)$, it means that the centralizer has index 1 or 2 in $G$. If it's $1$, then it is done - I'm failing to show why it must be so, unfortunately.

PS: I'm trying to prove that if $G$ is torsion-free, then $G \simeq \mathbb{Z}$. If I manage to prove that $H$ is central, then the transfer map $G \mapsto H$ is essentially multiplication by $[G\colon H]$, from which follows it must be injective and then we have it: any subgroup of $\mathbb{Z}$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}$.

---

I found an unsatisfactory way around using group cohomology (I believe that there is an elementary way of doing this though, so I'm leaving the question open). We can suppose, WLOG, that $[G\colon H] = 2$, simply by exchanging $H$ with $Z_G(H)$ and applying the proof for central subgroups. Then, we have an exact sequence:
$$\{1\} \to \mathbb{Z} \to G \to \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z} \to \{1\}$$

If $G/H$ acts trivially on $H$, we have that $Z_G(H) = G$ and we're done. Otherwise, $G/H$ must act by inverting the elements in $H$, and in particular $H^{G/H} = \{1\}$: there are no non-trivial fixed points. Such extensions $G$ are parametrized by $H^2(\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}, \mathbb{Z})$, and by the free periodic resolution over $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$, we have:
$$H^2(\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}, \mathbb{Z}) \simeq \mathbb{Z}^{\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}}/N\mathbb{Z} = \{1\}$$
where $N$ is the norm element. Thus, the only such extension is $\mathbb{Z} \rtimes \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$. This contradicts the hypothesis that $G$ is torsion-free.

Comment: Perhaps I'm missing something, but wouldn't $G=\mathbb{Z}\rtimes\mathbb{Z}_2$ with nontrivial action of $\mathbb{Z}_2$ on $\mathbb{Z}$ give a counterexample?

Comment: @user281392 yes it is. I guess I need the extra assumption of $G$ being torsion-free then.

Comment: Suppose you've already reduced to the case when $|G:H|=2$. Here is how to finish in an elementary way. Take $g\in G\setminus H$. Now, as you noted, either $g$ centralises $H$, and you are done, or it inverts every element in $H$. Assume the latter. Note that $g^2$ is in $H$ and centralised by $g$ so we must have $g^2=1$, and thus $G=H\rtimes \langle g\rangle$.

Comment: More generally, if $H$ is normal but not centralised by $G$ with $|G:H|=n<\infty$, take $g\in G\setminus Z_G(H)$, then $g^n$ is in $H$ and centralised by $g$, so $g^n=1$, and you have torsion.

Comment: @verret thanks! That's exactly the type of argument I was looking for. Would you make it an answer, so I can mark it as solved?

Comment: Actually, if $G$ is a virtually $\mathbf{Z}$ group, it has a (unique) maximal finite normal subgroup $F$ and $G/F$ is isomorphic to either $\mathbf{Z}$ or the infinite dihedral group $D_\infty$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By replacing $H$ with its core in $G$, we may assume that $H$ is normal in $G$ with $|G:H|=n< \infty$. Suppose there exists an element $g$  of $G$ that does not centralise $H$. Now, $g$ must act on $H$ by inversion, as this is the only non-identity automorphism of $\mathbb{Z}$. Note that $g^n$ is in $H$ so it is inverted by $g$. Since it is also centralised by $g$ and since the identity is the only involution in $H$, we have $g^n=1$. Note that $g\neq 1$, hence $G$ has torsion.